# Using WinRM for Windows 2012 R2 is throwing WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError

Tags: ruby, winrm, vcenter

I am using below code to connect to windows machine and getting WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError.

```
require 'winrm'
endpoint = 'http://server:5985/wsman'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'

winrm = WinRM::WinRMWebService.new(endpoint, :ssl, user: user, pass: password, disable_sspi: true)
winrm.run_cmd('ipconfig')
```

This is old framework and hence using old gem version 1.3.4. Can someone help me understand what mistake I'm doing here. I've tried proceeding username with domain still error remains same. It was working before and we recently upgraded windows to 2012R2 could that be an issue?

When I used latest gem 2.3.1 it is working properly but that means updating entire framework.

Note: I've tried running following on my server.

> Enable-PSRemoting –force
>
> winrm quickconfig

[image: And Output of get-service winrm is]

Comment: from the open source code: (https://github.com/WinRb/WinRM/blob/master/lib/winrm/http/response_handler.rb), you can see that it happened because your server returned 401 status, what means that you have a wrong credentials, it's a correct behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm using the same credentials to login to server and for the latest gem as well and it works perfectly.